# How can I put sql count value on a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I construct a code wherein it will count records where reservation_status = 'WAITING'. If the total number of waiting is >= 1, then it will show the records and perform the claiming of reservations. Else it will echo "The Unclaimed Reservations List is Empty".

This is my code:

```
  <?php
  $countsql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) FROM reservations WHERE reservation_status = 'WAITING';");
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($countsql);
  if ($count >= 1){          
  $select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reservation_status = 'WAITING';");
  while($userrow = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
        $reservationid=$userrow['reservation_id'];
        $startdate=$userrow['reservation_start_date'];
        $enddate=$userrow['reservation_end_date'];
        $cname=$userrow['customer_name'];
        $rroom=$userrow['reserved_room'];

                echo $rroom;?>
<a href="claimreservations.php?reservation_id=<?php echo $reservationid; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to claim this reservation?');"/>CLAIM RESERVATION</a>
  <?php}}else if($count = 0){
  echo "The Unclaimed Reservations List is Empty".}
?>
```

Now, I don't know why does it show both the records and this error message:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\system\admin pages\Reservations\view.php on line 6

Comment: `$count = 0` should be `$count == 0` and remove the `.` from this `echo "The Unclaimed Reservations List is Empty".`

Comment: have a second look at what `mysqli_num_rows` does. You do not want the number of results (always 1), but you want the actual result...

Comment: With mysqli_num_rows as mentioned above - you can drop the first SQL altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of executing two queries, do it in single query like below:-

```
<?php
$select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reservation_status = 'WAITING'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($select) >0){  
    while($userrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
        $reservationid  =   $userrow['reservation_id'];
        $startdate      =   $userrow['reservation_start_date'];
        $enddate        =   $userrow['reservation_end_date'];
        $cname          =   $userrow['customer_name'];
        $rroom          =   $userrow['reserved_room'];

        echo $rroom;
?>
<a href="claimreservations.php?reservation_id=<?php echo $reservationid; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to claim this reservation?');"/>CLAIM RESERVATION</a>
<?php }}else{
    echo "The Unclaimed Reservations List is Empty";
}?>
```

Comment: @Isaiah  please use my current edited answer code. I changed my answer code completely.

Comment: @DoriesIsaiah  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

I think its because `mysqli_num_rows()` will return rows count, which is always 1

use

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($countsql, MYSQLI_NUM);
if ($result[0] >= 1) { // so
```